# PostgreSQL calculate difference between rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to calculate difference between rows in a field using a query:

```
Illustrations:
input:year,month,fixes
output:increase

     year | month | fixes    | increase
    ------+-------+----------+-----------
     2006 | 04    |       1  | 0
     2006 | 05    |       4  | 3
     2006 | 06    |       3  | -1
```

Increase column as output by difference between adjacent rows in fixes.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: increase column as output

Answer (score 146, accepted):

This is what window functions are for:

```
select year, 
       month,
       fixes,
       fixes - lag(fixes) over (order by year, month) as increase,
from the_table;
```

For more details please see the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html