# find diff between 2 numbers in different rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table writing every minute int value (requests count).
I have some requests types on some servers, all of them on the same table:

```
time                |  key1    | key2      | key3   | value     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-16 18:00:53 | server1  | webpage1  | type1  | 30
2017-01-16 18:00:55 | server1  | webpage2  | type1  | 31
2017-01-16 18:00:58 | server1  | webpage3  | type1  | 32
2017-01-16 18:00:59 | server1  | webpage4  | type1  | 33
2017-01-16 18:01:00 | server1  | webpage5  | type1  | 34
2017-01-16 18:01:01 | server1  | webpage6  | type1  | 35
2017-01-16 18:01:02 | server1  | webpage7  | type1  | 36
2017-01-16 18:01:03 | server1  | webpage8  | type1  | 37
2017-01-16 18:01:04 | server1  | webpage1  | type1  | 56
2017-01-16 18:01:06 | server1  | webpage2  | type1  | 35
2017-01-16 18:01:07 | server1  | webpage3  | type1  | 43
2017-01-16 18:01:10 | server1  | webpage4  | type1  | 64
2017-01-16 18:01:13 | server1  | webpage5  | type1  | 44
2017-01-16 18:01:14 | server1  | webpage6  | type1  | 66
2017-01-16 18:01:16 | server1  | webpage7  | type1  | 56
2017-01-16 18:01:18 | server1  | webpage8  | type1  | 22
```

Assume key1 and key3 has different values as well (for the sake of this example I emitted some data).

I need the result to be the diff of the latest value on group (key1, key2, key3) minus the 1 offset of the latest [I need the rate per minute].

I successfully got the result of the latest and 1 offset of it in the same table (grouped by key):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY key1, key2, key3 ORDER BY time DESC) as rnum,
 time, key1, key2, key3, value FROM test ORDER BY time DESC) a
WHERE rnum < 3;
```

So the result is:

```
 rnum |        time         |  key1   |   key2   | key3  | value
------+---------------------+---------+----------+-------+-------
    1 | 2017-01-16 18:01:18 | server1 | webpage8 | type1 |    22
    1 | 2017-01-16 18:01:16 | server1 | webpage7 | type1 |    56
    1 | 2017-01-16 18:01:14 | server1 | webpage6 | type1 |    66
    1 | 2017-01-16 18:01:13 | server1 | webpage5 | type1 |    44
    1 | 2017-01-16 18:01:10 | server1 | webpage4 | type1 |    64
    1 | 2017-01-16 18:01:07 | server1 | webpage3 | type1 |    43
    1 | 2017-01-16 18:01:06 | server1 | webpage2 | type1 |    35
    1 | 2017-01-16 18:01:04 | server1 | webpage1 | type1 |    56
    2 | 2017-01-16 18:01:03 | server1 | webpage8 | type1 |    37
    2 | 2017-01-16 18:01:02 | server1 | webpage7 | type1 |    36
    2 | 2017-01-16 18:01:01 | server1 | webpage6 | type1 |    35
    2 | 2017-01-16 18:01:00 | server1 | webpage5 | type1 |    34
    2 | 2017-01-16 18:00:59 | server1 | webpage4 | type1 |    33
    2 | 2017-01-16 18:00:58 | server1 | webpage3 | type1 |    32
    2 | 2017-01-16 18:00:55 | server1 | webpage2 | type1 |    31
    2 | 2017-01-16 18:00:53 | server1 | webpage1 | type1 |    30
```

Now, I thought i can take the value column of MIN(time) and MAX(time) and calc the diff, but I cannot "merge" the lines.

After @HartCO Comment I was able to do this:

```
select time, new_val-last_val, key1, key2, key3 from
  (select distinct max(time)  over(partition by key1, key2, key3) as time,
          max(value) over(partition by key1, key2, key3) as new_val,
          min(value) over(partition by key1, key2, key3) as last_val,
          key1, key2, key3
   from (select row_number() over(partition by key1, key2, key3 order by time desc) as rnum, 
                time, key1, key2, key3, value from test order by time desc) a 
where rnum < 3) b;
```

And I got:

```
    time         | ?column? |  key1   |   key2   | key3
---------------------+----------+---------+----------+-------
2017-01-16 18:01:14 |       31 | server1 | webpage6 | type1
2017-01-16 18:01:18 |       15 | server1 | webpage8 | type1
2017-01-16 18:01:16 |       20 | server1 | webpage7 | type1
2017-01-16 18:01:04 |       26 | server1 | webpage1 | type1
2017-01-16 18:01:13 |       10 | server1 | webpage5 | type1
2017-01-16 18:01:06 |        4 | server1 | webpage2 | type1
2017-01-16 18:01:07 |       11 | server1 | webpage3 | type1
2017-01-16 18:01:10 |       31 | server1 | webpage4 | type1
```

But the desired output should be **-15** on webpage8, not 22.

Comment: You seem close, just as you have used `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` you can use `MIN(time) OVER(...) and same for `MAX()` to get those values relative to group of rows defined by the `PARTITION BY` clause (no `ORDER BY` used for those two.

Comment: @HartCO - can you please give as example for MAX and MIN with OVER?

Comment: @HartCO - See my edit. But it is not good enough. if the counter decrease I will not catch it, I am doing max(val) and min(val) and it is not correlated to the max(time) and min(time)

Comment: Could you take your sample data and show what the desired output is to help clarify?

Comment: @HartCO - Yes , I will edit my sample data with that specific case and add the desired output

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691462/postgresql-calculate-difference-between-rows. This'll be a lot easier using [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).

Comment: Re-reading your updated question, I agree with @IljaEverilä `LAG()` and `LEAD()` can be used to return values from other rows, and you can use those in calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of differences between rows offset by some amount are best handled with the [`lag()` and `lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) window functions. For getting the **latest** value [you can use `DISTINCT ON` combined with `ORDER BY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/2681632), if your tables aren't huge. Note that `DISTINCT ON` is a Postgresql extension.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (key1, key2, key3)
       time,
       key1,
       key2,
       key3,
       value - lag(value) OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2, key3 ORDER BY time) 
FROM test
ORDER BY key1, key2, key3, time DESC;
```

This gives us

```
        time         |    key1    |    key2     |   key3   | ?column? 
---------------------+------------+-------------+----------+----------
 2017-01-16 18:01:04 |  server1   |  webpage1   |  type1   |       26
 2017-01-16 18:01:06 |  server1   |  webpage2   |  type1   |        4
 2017-01-16 18:01:07 |  server1   |  webpage3   |  type1   |       11
 2017-01-16 18:01:10 |  server1   |  webpage4   |  type1   |       31
 2017-01-16 18:01:13 |  server1   |  webpage5   |  type1   |       10
 2017-01-16 18:01:14 |  server1   |  webpage6   |  type1   |       31
 2017-01-16 18:01:16 |  server1   |  webpage7   |  type1   |       20
 2017-01-16 18:01:18 |  server1   |  webpage8   |  type1   |      -15
(8 rows)
```

Of course you can use the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748986/get-records-with-highest-smallest-whatever-per-group) well [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/) [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) solutions, for example a left join.

```
WITH diffs AS (
    SELECT time,
           key1,
           key2,
           key3,
           value - lag(value) OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2, key3 ORDER BY time)
    FROM test)
SELECT d1.*
FROM diffs d1
LEFT JOIN diffs d2
  ON (d1.key1, d1.key2, d1.key3) = (d2.key1, d2.key2, d2.key3)
 -- This allows us to single out the greatest row
 AND d1.time < d2.time
WHERE d2.time IS NULL
-- Ordering is just for show
ORDER BY d1.key1, d1.key2, d1.key3;
```

Using Postgresql 9.5 the planner recognized this pattern and used an anti join as the final query plan. You could also get similar results using `NOT EXISTS`.