# Rails query for difference between has_many association records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model called `Student`, that `has_many` `Test`s. Each `Test` has a column named `mark`. I'd like to

- query and sort students based on the greatest average test marks
- query and sort students based on the greatest difference between first and last test (assuming marks are increasing)
- query and sort students based on the difference between 2 tests

I am stuck at the part where I am creating the select query for the test marks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to provide raw SQL query so for the first task I assume this query should work

```
SELECT students.*, AVG(COALESCE(tests.mark, 0)) as avg_mark FROM students LEFT OUTER JOIN tests ON students.id = tests.student_id GROUP BY students.id ORDER BY avg_mark
```

For the second task I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691462/postgresql-calculate-difference-between-rows) post, I think it should work, but didn't check

```
SELECT students.*, MIN(LAG(COALESCE(tests.mark, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY tests.mark) as mark_diff) as min_mark FROM students LEFT OUTER JOIN tests ON students.id = tests.student_id GROUP BY students.id ORDER BY min_mark
```

I didn't fully understand the last task. I assume it is the maximal difference between tests for the student

```
SELECT students.*, MIN(LAG(COALESCE(tests.mark, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY tests.mark) as mark_diff) as min_mark FROM students LEFT OUTER JOIN tests ON students.id = tests.student_id GROUP BY students.id ORDER BY min_mark
```

To make it more rails way try this:

```
Student.select('students.*, MIN(LAG(COALESCE(tests.mark, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY tests.mark) as mark_diff) as min_mark').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN tests ON students.id = tests.student_id').group('students.id').order('min_mark')
```

But after aggregate functions, you'll not be able to add any scope to the result relation. You can try to do two queries for it, providing the list of ids to the result

```
scope :my_scope, -> { ids = my_request.pluck(:id); where(id: ids) }
```

The possible pitfall is in maximal query size.